# What about a module of rank $\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. The possible ranks of free $R$-modules are $0,1,2,\dotsc$. But what about a generalized notion of an $R$-module where ranks may be rational numbers such as $\frac{1}{2}$?

More specifically, is there any (natural) cocomplete [symmetric monoidal category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+monoidal+category) which contains $\mathsf{Mod}(R)$ and a distinguished object $T$ satisfying $T \oplus T \cong R$?

Remark that for $R \neq 0$ there is no $R$-module $T$ which satisfies $T \oplus T \cong R$, because otherwise $T$ would be finitely generated projective, hence locally free of finite rank $d$ with $2d=1$, a contradiction.

Background: I try to develope some kind of "functional calculus" for monoidal categories. This example here deals with $n$th roots, for which we have to adjoin $\frac{1}{n}$ first. More precisely, if some object $T$ has the property $n \cdot T \cong 1$, where $1$ is the unit for $\otimes$, we may think of $T$ as a [categorification](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0004133) of $\frac{1}{n}$ and define an object $(1 \oplus M)^{\frac{1}{n}} := \bigoplus_{p=0}^{\infty} \Lambda^p(T) \otimes M^{\otimes p}$, which in fact is a $n$th root of $1 \oplus M$ with respect to $\otimes$. This is a categorification of the binomial theorem $(1+z)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/n}{p} z^p$ for $z \in \mathbb{C},\,|z|<1$.

Comment: The mystery category cannot contain Mod(R) as a full subcategory, what would the composite $R \cong T \oplus T \to T \hookrightarrow R$ (where the map to $T$ is one of the projections) be?

Comment: Yeah probably it will just be a subcategory or even just admit a tensor functor $\mathsf{Mod}(R) \to C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no, at least when $2 \in R^*$. If $C$ is a cocomplete $R$-linear symmetric monoidal category with an object $T$ satisfying $1 \cong T \oplus T$, then $C=0$.

Proof: We have [exterior powers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70607) in $C$ with the usual properties. Hence, $0 = \Lambda^2 (T \oplus T) \cong (\Lambda^2 T) \oplus (\Lambda^1 T \otimes \Lambda^1 T) \oplus (\Lambda^2 T)$, which means $\Lambda^2 T = 0$ and $T \otimes T = 0$. But then $T \cong 1 \otimes T \cong (T \oplus T) \otimes T \cong (T \otimes T) \oplus (T \otimes T) = 0$, hence $1 = 0$. $\square$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can adapt the idea of groupoid cardinality.

Given a skeletal groupoid, we define its cardinality to be the

$$ |G| = \sum_X \frac{1}{|\hom(X, X)|} $$

where $X$ ranges over its objects.

So, for example, the cyclic group of two elements, viewed as a category, is a groupoid with cardinality $1/2$.

So, maybe you can make sense of having fractional if you consider modules with endomorphisms acting on them. Maybe an example of a "rank $1/2$" module should be a module $M$ together with a choice of involution acting on it?

More generally, maybe it's worth looking at combinatorial species, which can be used to do something that sounds similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: So you are saying that the category of $R[\mathbb{Z}/2]$-modules is what I am looking for? What is $T$ here?

Comment: It's a suggestion of an approach you can try for your research and a pointer to literature you may not have been aware of. If you aren't interested in such things and only want complete solutions to your question, then you should say so. *grumpy*

Comment: I am aware of these notions. Your answer doesn't help me. What is $T$?

Comment: I've investigated this idea $\mathbb{Z}/2$ in detail and have come to the conclusion that it doesn't answer the question. Roughly we get decompositions $M=M_+ \oplus M_-$ (eigenspaces w.r.t to $+1$ and $-1$), but $M_+ \neq M_-$, so this is not what I want.